# Some Javascript Cookie Reading

Tags: javascript, cookies

```
function readCookie(name)
{
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  for(var i=0; i < ca.length; i++) {
var c = ca[i];
while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length); //delete spaces
if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
}
  return null;
}

document.ready(function() {

var color = readCookie(go);

if (color != null) {

var gs = document.createElement("link");
gs.type = "text/css";
gs.rel = "stylesheet";
gs.title = "mystyle"
gs.href = "images/audentio/gogreen/green.css";

var rs = document.createElement("link");
rs.type = "text/css";
rs.rel = "stylesheet";
rs.title = "mystyle"
rs.href = "images/audentio/gogreen/red.css";

var bs = document.createElement("link");
bs.type = "text/css";
bs.rel = "stylesheet";
bs.title = "mystyle"
bs.href = "images/audentio/gogreen/blue.css";

if (color == "green"){
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(rs);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(bs);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(gs);
}

else if (color == "blue"){
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(rs);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(gs);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(bs);
}

else (color == "red"){
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(gs);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(bs);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(rs);
}
}
else {
return: false;
}
});
```

Hey guys, I'm no good with this stuff, it's killing all the jQuery in my page (Though for reasons I won't go into, I don't want to use jQuery for the reading of the cookie, only the creating of it) so any chance someone can see the error?

Live Demo: http://wedesignthe.net/staff_uploads/eric/ad_development/demo/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find `else (color == "red"){` and replace with `else if(color == "red"){`

The error due to this statement `else (color == "red"){` where you just forgot `if`

and change

```
else {
    return: false;
}
```

to

```
else {
    return false;
}
```

`remove : between return and false`

and change `document.ready(function() {` to `$(document).ready(function() {` or `$(function() {`

Replace it

```
if (color == "green"){
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(rs);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(bs);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(gs);
}

else if (color == "blue"){
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(rs);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(gs);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(bs);
}

else if (color == "red"){
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(gs);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(bs);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(rs);
}
```

with

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var links = head.getElementsByTagName("link");
for(var x=0; x<links.length ; x++)
{
   var href = links[x].href;
    if(href.indexOf('/green.css') >0 || href.indexOf('/red.css') >0|| href.indexOf('/blue.css') >0){
      head.removeChild(links[x]);
   }
}

if (color == "green"){
    head.appendChild(gs);
}
else if (color == "blue"){
    head.appendChild(bs);
}

else if (color == "red"){
   head.appendChild(rs);
}
```

Comment: @EricJackson, and change `document.ready(function() {` to `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: updated code didn't fix it. Yeah with or without noConflict()

Comment: @EricJackson, updated code was working, but the problem was it is not getting the head tag.

Comment: If it were working my color picker would also be working. None of the jQuery is working so long as this is bugged.

Comment: @EricJackson, Check the updated answer and replace that code with and check.

Comment: and remove `return false;` if not wrapping in any function.

Comment: @EricJackson, `readCookie(name)` function should be out side of `jQuery(function()` and call it with `readCookie('go')`

Comment: none of it seems to be working, I've tried just about everything. :/

Comment: @EricJackson, First remove extra `}` before `});`

Comment: I tried some things and it's working, but the cookies don't work.

Comment: @EricJackson, change var color = readCookie(go); to var color = readCookie("go");

Comment: @EricJackson, now change the loop `for(var x in links)` to `for(var x=0; x<links.length; x++)`

Comment: Works, thanks a bunch. Though I still get FOUC, was hoping not using jQuery would fix that. :/

Comment: @EricJackson, issue was not jQuery, only the use of function, elements and there scope was causing problem

Comment: Well, thanks again, and I got rid of the FOUC by moving the included functions.js file to the correct place in templates. Everything is working 100% now.